# Using vector std::find with a user-created object - third argument

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, find

I am trying to make use of `std::find` to search a vector and return an iterator of the required object is found. The problem I am having is that I am not sure what to put as the third argument. Below is the relevant line of code as well as the definition of the object I am using.

**Function:**

```
vector<Vertex>::const_iterator findV = find(testV.begin(), testV.end(), vtx); 
//vtx is of type Vertex
```

**Class Definition:**

```
class Vertex
{
    private:
        int currentIndex;
        double xPoint, yPoint, zPoint;
        vector<double> vertexAttributes;

    public:
        Vertex();
        ~Vertex();

        friend istream& operator>>(istream&, Vertex &);
        friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Vertex &);

        double getIndex(){return currentIndex;}
        double get_xPoint(){return xPoint;}
        double get_yPoint(){return yPoint;}
        double get_zPoint(){return zPoint;}
};
```

Logically I would assume that since I am searching for an object of type `Vertex`, the third argument should also be of this type, but this does not work.

The error received is:

```
error: no match for 'operator==' (operand types are 'Vertex' and 'const Vertex')|
```

Please let me know if any further clarification is required.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look at your error message, and ask yourself how `std::find` is supposed to know when it has found the item you're looking for.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley by checking whether or not `testV.end()` has been reached right? I don't think that this has anything to do with why I am getting the error though.

Please correct me if I am wrong, I am no expert.

Comment: No, that's how *you* check if `std::find` found your item. What do you think  `std::find` does each time it examines an element in order to determine if it is the correct one?

Comment: It compares it to the element provided in the third argument?

Comment: And how does it compare them?

Comment: Using the operator ==.

Comment: Which I'm guessing I'd need to overload...

Comment: @CollinOladimeji _"Which I'm guessing I'd need to overload..."_ Bingo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to overload the `==` operator for your `Vertex` class so `std::find` understands when one vertex is the same as another. This is what Benjamin was trying to walk you to.

The code for `std::find` can be found at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find/

```
template<class InputIterator, class T>
  InputIterator find (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& val)
{
  while (first!=last) {
    if (*first==val) return first;
    ++first;
  }
  return last;
}
```

Hopefully that code makes it more clear as to what is going on.

Comment: Thank you. I don't mean to sound like a complete programming moron, it's part of my Engineering degree at university and I'm not (yet) the best at it.

Comment: We have all been there. It's easier to understand once you find the code for std::find. It's always useful to search information about the standard library.